# Как в batch файле обработать нескольких сброшенных на него файлов?

Tags: bat, ffmpeg, drag-n-drop

Один файл без проблем:

`ffmpeg -i "%~1" "%~n1.gif"`

Как обработать группу из нескольких сброшенных (drag and drop) файлов?
Пробовал:

```
for %%a in (%*) do (
    ffmpeg "%%a~1" "%%a~n1.gif"
)
```

не работает.

Comment: @Kromster drag and drop файла на batch файл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать shift

```
@echo off
:nextfile
ffmpeg -i "%~1" "%~n1.gif"
shift
if "%~1" neq "" goto nextfile
```